# How to give .htaccess RewriteRule for specific file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to write `.htaccess` rule to specific `REQUEST_FILENAME` like below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/my_file.txt
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

This specific file is 0kb file size. Already I have a rule to ignore those files like

```
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s     
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`
```

This empty file is used for analytical usage.

but this is not work as I expected. I just want to if `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `my_file.txt` read it as it is. Is there any syntax or any error in above code?

Thanks...

Comment: Just insert this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !my_file.txt  [NC]` before the rewrite rule and the condition.

Comment: Not exactly. Put that line before the last 2 lines in your question. Before this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s `.

Comment: @faa Yah this seems correct answer for that. please put as an answer if you want vote up :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks, I will do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to exclude `my_file.txt` from the rule, is like this:

```php
# Insert the next line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !my_file\.txt [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s     
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule !^/?my_file\.txt - [NC,L]
```

This will match every file other than my_file.txt, and if it is a 0size file rewriting ends.

> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
>
> In mod_rewrite, the NOT character ('!') is also available as a
>   possible pattern prefix. This enables you to negate a pattern; to say,
>   for instance: ``if the current URL does NOT match this pattern''.